# two steps filtering, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a data frame with two columns: 'City' and 'Number'

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'City':['1','1','3','4'],'Number':['3-1','42','23','3-4']})
```

If I want to filter by City, lets say City == 1. I can do this:

```
df[df['City']=='1']
```

And got this:

```
    City    Number
0   1   3-1
1   1   42
```

But I also want to filter by number.

How can I only get the items For City == 1, and with number that have a '-'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df[(df.City=='1') & (df.Number.str.contains('-'))]
```